# Can I bold a portion of my h1 tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make one h1 tag in HTML that has only a few words out of the entire thing bolded, but every time I try to implement this, it makes the entire h1 tag bold.

```
<div class="main-info">
    <h1>
        Some <strong>text</strong> here
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`h1` is bold by default.

Apply `font-weight:normal` to the `h1` if you only want the text wrapped in `strong` tags to be bold:

```css
h1{
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-info">
    <h1>
        Some <strong>text</strong> here
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1{
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-info">
    <h1>
        Some <b>text</b> here
    </h1>
</div>
```

This will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code into internal / external CSS/

```
<style>
.main-info{
  font-weight:normal;
}
</style>
```

```
<div class="main-info">
    <h1>
        Some <strong>text</strong> here
    </h1>
</div>
```